# grails 2.0.4 + batch-launcher plugin - can't resolve Log4jConfigListener

Tags: grails, plugins

I have asked the following question on the Grails fora, but no replies. I wonder if Stackoverflow could be more successful?

I can't get batch-launcher plugin to install in Grails 2.0.4. The import for Log4jConfigListener in its 'Launcher' class fails because it can't be found.

I have seen a warning in the 'upgrading to 2.0.4' section of the Grails doc, that says you if you have customised the web.xml provided by install-templates, you must update this with the latest from Grails.

I wonder if there could be something similar happening with the batch-launcher plugin?

Regards, John

Comment: what is the full path for the import?

Answer (score 1):

we are using the batch launcher plugin with grails 2.1 and we had the same problem at the beginning.

We solved the problem by downloading the sources and patching the Plugin:
- adapt the import package for Log4jConfigListener
- adapt _BatchWar.groovy to include the jar files (grails 2.0 changed the location of some jar files which are used by the batch)

Afterwards it is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

I made the changes per Tobias' comment, if anyone is interested I put the working plugin on on Gihub that works with Grails 2. [here](https://github.com/alidadasb/grails-batch-launcher-plugin)